# I want to create byte buddy subclasses for my controller class. I don't have source code. I have create dynamic classes in another project

Tags: java, spring-boot, byte-buddy

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String homePage() {
        return "welcome to homepage";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this with bytebuddy?

Comment: I am new to java agent and byte code instrumentation. If you have any suggestions plese let me know.

Comment: That isn't really an answer to my question, why would you need byte-buddy for this? You can just create a sub class.

Comment: You can create a subclass by using new ByteBuddy().subclass(type).make(). What is the purpose of this subclass?

Comment: The above code is available in the spring boot project but I don't have the source code. I want to create a home controller subclass in another project then I will create my own endpoints and I can access them.